# Why Listeners are interdependent on one another in Java?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, mouselistener

I have written MineSweeper game. In that I have two Listeners for a button as,

```
 class SampleClass extends MouseAdapter implements ActionListener  {

         //Some code here

          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){ // Buttons listener..
               System.out.println("I came here to actionPerformed.");
               //Some Code
          }

         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) { //Mouse listener..
               System.out.println("I came here to MouseClicked.");
              //Some Code
               if(event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3){..}//If Right Mouse Button Is Clicked!!
               else if(event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){..}//If Left Mouse Button Is Clicked!!
         }
 }
```

What I observed is , whenever **left button of mouse is clicked, the only actionPerformed is called and not mouseClicked**. But on the click of the right button of mouse, mouseClicked is called ( and as in normal case , actionPerformed is not called).

But, **When I remove the ActionListener**, then on **both clicks** of left and right mouse buttons **mouseClicked is called** and works perfectly fine.

I thought, the two listeners to be two different independent threads, listening for the events, **But why one depends on other?**

Comment: which framework are you referring to?

Comment: @sanbhat JButton . I didnt get the word framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No two listeners are not dependent on each other. It is the property of `JButton` to fire an `Action` if it is pressed, either by `space bar` , or calling `doClick` or by `left click` of mouse. That's why `actionperformed` is called by default(given that the `ActionListener` is registered with it) when you press the `JButton` by left click of mouse but before `actionPerformed` is called , `mousePressed` event is called.  And in case the `ActionListener` is not registered with the `JButton` , `MouseEvent` comes into play and the required action is performed. Two Listeners work independently of each other. In fact actions are fired in a proper sequence.. for Example for `JButton` if ActionListener and MouseListener both are registered .. Then the sequence of actions fired is as follows:

1. mousePressed()
2. actionPerformed()
3. mouseReleased()
4. mouseClicked()

This code would make you clear about these points.:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
class Listeners extends JFrame
{
    public void prepareAndShowGUI()
    {
        setTitle("Listeners dependency");
        JButton button = new JButton("Click");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
            {
                System.out.println("Action Listener has listened.");
            }
        });
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt)
            {
                System.out.println("Mouse Clicked.");
            }
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt)
            {
                System.out.println("Mouse pressed.");
            }
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt)
            {
                System.out.println("Mouse Released.");
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(button);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String stp[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Listeners listen = new Listeners();
                listen.prepareAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

on Clicking the JButton following output is obtained:

```
Mouse pressed.
Action Listener has listened.
Mouse Released.
Mouse Clicked.
```

Answer (score 0):

AWT's `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener` handling acts very strange sometime.
But as what I think events should not interfere with each other.

If a component has no mouse listener
then mouse events are raised up to the parent container. This means you
can get away with listening to a parent component, and still receive
events for all of its children.In the above usecase which if some other code adds a mouse listener to a child component than mouse events will not bubble up to parent container.
This is really a bad design.

I prefer to use mouse listener if and only if I am writing a subclass of a JComponent or a PL&F because they can get overidden by other events listeners.So i guess this is what happened in your case.And one suggestion is to use [EventQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) that should serve your purpose.